# Twice blessed with immortality

Tags: chandra, immortality

Chandra Deva,the Moon God, required a booster dose to restore His immortality. It seems that the sip of Amrita was not enough to ensure his survival against the wrath of Daksha.

The waning moon was rescued by the chants of Maha Mrityunjaya Mantra.

Are there any other such instances in our scriptures ?

Comment: He was still immortal. His curse was of Kshaya-roga, which meant that he would reduce and increase constantly. He didn't die. He was married to Daksha's daughters. If the curse was for him to die, then Daksha is making his own daughters widows. That was never his intention. Death is an easy escape. The curse is to make Chandra suffer and continue to live through the suffering. All typical curses are like that. They don't kill the cursed person. They make him live and suffer.